# How to filter taxonomy terms in WP Admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm trying to filter a custom taxonomy in the backend of my wordpress site to allow certain users to use only some of the available entries.
Through the Advanced Custom Fields plugin I have created a custom metabox in the user panel that allows me to disable or enable at will a list of terms (WP_Terms) among those existing in my custom taxonomy.
But now I need to show only the terms selected from the user page in the WordPress post editor.
This is the code I have come up with so far but it seems that I have run aground.

```
function filter_admin_allowed_regions ( $terms, $id, $taxonomy ) {
    $terms = wp_cache_get( $id, "{$taxonomy}_relationships_sorted" );
    $newTerms = array();
    if(is_admin())
    if ( $taxonomy->name == "regioni" ) {
        $allowed = the_field('tassonomie_abilitate', 'user_'.get_current_user_id());
        return $allowed;
    }
    return $terms;
    }
    add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'filter_admin_allowed_regions' , 10, 4 );
```

Comment: _“but it seems that I have run aground”_ might qualify as a “problem description” among pirates, but not here. Please go read [ask].

Comment: `the_field` will echo the field. You want `get_field` if you're returning it.

Comment: I like the description and the description of the description by Broe. "Problem description among pirates", lol... Howard's right, `the_field` agrounded your code :)